# AnimateLayoutChanges and Background painting

Tags: android, view, background, android-linearlayout

I've got a view with animate layout changes to true in a dialog with a Theme giving it a background color.

When a view from my dialog has its visibility changing from Gone to Visible, I can see the region being painted (from white to my background color).

Is there a way not to see that background painting animation while keeping the layout change animation ?